# using a list of labels and a larger list to create a dictionary in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I got a list of labels = ('id','price', 'interest','bid','ask','vol')
then I have another list that could be of any length but, the the values of that list cycle to match the order of the labels.

In other words I'll get a list of numbers of: id, price, interest, bid, ask, vol ... to repeat  price, interst, bid, ask, vol and on and on until I run out of values. 
And as I iterate over those 5 numbers, I want to match them to the 5 labels in a dict of a dict that would key off of the ID and then from the ID, I could look up price.

So, I don't think a zip would work.

Ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[`itertools`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) to the rescue!

You need both `zip`/`izip` and [`cycle`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle).

```
labels = ('price', 'interest','bid','ask','vol')
list2 = ... # whatever you have

itertools.izip(labels, itertools.cycle(list2))
```

Well, `zip`/`izip` is maybe not really needed. Depends what you will do...

Answer (score 1):

Use `itertools.cycle`:

help on `itertools.cycle`: `cycle(iterable) --> cycle object`

> Return elements from the iterable until it is exhausted. Then repeat
>   the sequence indefinitely.

**Demo:**

```
>>> from itertools import cycle
>>> labels = ('price', 'interest','bid','ask','vol')
>>> labels_cyc = cycle(labels)
>>> values = range(15)
```

Now simply iterate over values list at fetch the corresponding value from `labels_cyc` using `next(labels_cyc)`:

```
>>> for val in values:
...     print val, next(labels_cyc)
...     
0 price
1 interest
2 bid
3 ask
4 vol
5 price
6 interest
7 bid
8 ask
9 vol
10 price
11 interest
12 bid
13 ask
14 vol
```